# nodejs calendar api quickstart app browser requires https

Tags: node.js

I try to run the quickstart app for the calendar app. It pops up ont the browser however after the last verification step it displays "`ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`". I assume this is because the redirect URL is http://localhost. How can I specify it should use HTTPS? I also have a self-signed certificate. Can I somewhere specify the server options?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the authenticate function creates it's own http server and listen on port 3000. Googles authenticate server will make a get request on it to tell the code for autenticate, however google chrome redirects this request to https and its security policies for localhost do not accept http. To solve this problem, I could delete the browsers's security policies for localhost. Then the quickstart example ist working.
See how: https://superuser.com/questions/565409/how-to-stop-an-automatic-redirect-from-http-to-https-in-chrome